# Rspec and Device on controller. 'You are being redirected'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I found that there are not enough posts about this subject so I decide to post the question ones again.

I am simply trying to test my controllers that use devise with rspec .

I did add in rails_helper.rb

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

I wrote this test:

```
describe AlbumsController do
    render_views
    let(:user) { User.create!(email: "rspec@example.com", password: "password") }
    before(:each) do
        sign_in(user)
    end
    it "should have a current_user" do
        subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
    end
    describe "get ALBUM index" do
        describe "for a registred user" do
            it "should => index page" do
                get :index
                response.should have_selector('div#photos')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and my index method is really executed! I added some puts to follow the execution.
The subject.current_user is not null. everything should be good.

But I get a message:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/main\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

There is No particular redirect_to or render method in my index action. It just render the default.

What is the problem here?

I'm using gem 'devise', "2.2.8" and gem 'rails', "3.2.1". It is old I know. I try to add tests before the migration to Rails 4 :-/

EDIT 1:

The current_user is valid in my index method.
It means it is not a Devise problem. but the view that is rendered

Comment: please, format the spec code properly

Comment: I'm wondering if the response view is really rendered ? Maybe I get this <html> page "You are being redirected" because the view is not rendered

Comment: There is a high possibility that you are simply not signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such construction

```
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29

Comment: Did not solve the problem (I'm using gem 'devise', "2.2.8" and gem 'rails', "3.2.1") It's old I know

Comment: Well, is the user record valid? Is it confirmed? Check it.

Comment: I feel like the authentication is ok because I put some puts "hello" in my index action and they are all executed. At the end of my index action I just let the method render the defaut index html

Comment: great idea Stanislav. How do I do that?

Comment: Then provide your controller and application_controller code

Comment: make some "puts user.valid?; puts user.confirmed?"

Comment: The user is valid inside the index method.
But method confirmed does not exist I'm not using the rails confirmable module.

Comment: Then provide your controller and app_controller code

Comment: Ok I found the solution: it is because I need to perform the should search on response.body and not response

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:
before { request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on' }

Answer (score 0):

If you have devise confirmable turned on you might have to confirm your user before signing in.

```rb
...
before do
  user = create(:user)
  user.confirm
  sign_in(user)
end
...
```